# How to remove an event listener in NodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream

I can't figure out how this is supposed to be implemented. Every time I try, it either complains that removeEventListener is not a function, or some other random error. Currently this is in the context of being used as chunks of data are written into a file, and I need to use drain occassionally and then remove the drain listener. I'll get the error

```
(node:8996) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [WriteStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

and then eventually run out of heap memory for JavaScript. I'm trying to not increase the allowed memory, however if that's about the only useful thing I can do then let me know

My current code looks like this because I have no idea what I'm doing

```
fileWrite: async function AddressesToFile(chunk, fileS, done) {
    console.log("Writing chunk in");

    var writeCon = true;

    //Writes the chunk into the output filestream
    for (var i=0;i<chunk.length;i++) {
        //Split the address line along the custom separators used
        for (var ii=0;ii<chunk[i].split("(|S|)").length;ii++) {
            if (ii == 0) {
                //Add quotes around the first element (the original address string)
                writeCon = fileS.write('"' + chunk[i].split("(|S|)")[ii] + '",');
            } else if (ii == chunk[i].split("(|S|)").length-1) {
                //Add a newline after each element
                writeCon = fileS.write(chunk[i].split("(|S|)")[ii] + '\n');
            } else {
                //Add a comma after last element
                writeCon = fileS.write(chunk[i].split("(|S|)")[ii] + ',');
            }
        }
    }

    if (!writeCon) {
        fileS.once('drain', (drain) => fileS.removeEventListeners('drain', (drain) => console.log('Drained')));
    }

    //If we have sent the last chunk through, close the file stream
    /*if (done) {
        fileS.end();
        extractDone = true;
    }*/

},
```

The origin data is read in the form of uncleaned addresses, my code turns them into strings with the uncleaned address, post code, components found, and a score of components found attached to it which then gets written to a destination file

Comment: Show your code where you're adding this listener in the first place.

Comment: Updated, sorry I'm being slack I'm just getting annoyed with this project

Comment: This looks like a doozie.  :-)  Can you show what the format is that you're trying to write to a file?  We can probably help you refactor it.  Also, consider implementing a TransformStream instead of this.  That way, you can pipe the output wherever.  What you're doing with the drain and what not doesn't make sense.

Comment: Its an array where each element contains a string, the (|S|) are custom separators I used to help the code format the lines because the original text contains random things that I would normally use as separators, but can't because they're already in there

Comment: Also I tried a transform stream and had no idea how to work it, so I gave up with that

Comment: Why not use one of the many off-the-shelf CSV encoders?  They have built-in escape sequences so you don't have to worry about the separators in the strings.  Or, something standard like JSON or CBOR?

Comment: It takes a few weeks to get approval for a new package to add to a language per project. Its an annoying system, and the reason I'm trying to implement it is because I tried to add worker threads to my code but it let to the result of heap memory overflow. I looked it up and read that I likely needed to drain my stream, and so that's where I am at the moment, trying to figure out how I'm supposed to drain it and remove the drain listener to prevent memory overflow

Comment: Can you show us an actual example of the data, and the actual example of the line you want to write?

Comment: How is that related to removing event listeners?

Comment: I was going to help you refactor this, but if you'd rather I don't, fine.  You have a lot of misconceptions here, and I thought I'd help you get pointed in the right direction.  Please edit your question with the example... the comments box is eating the formatting.  Also, if that isn't a fake name/address... please make it one.

Comment: There's 5 million lines in this file so I can't post all the original data, but the lines are all like that

Comment: To answer your question exactly... you can use `.off()`.  But this of course does nothing to solve your actual problem.

Comment: I'm not asking you to post your file, I'm asking you to show us what you're trying to do, in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213374/discussion-between-thebasementnerd-and-brad).